# Reference .xaml file to a .cs file from another folder

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, reference

Can anyone help me with a problem? I found some solutions but it didnt worked for me. I have to use a part of xaml code to implement a fuctionality on a service, more exacty I have to open location settings from the service soo, in that way I need some xaml code. How exactly can I reference a .xaml file from views to a .cs from services?

[image: Files layout]

Answer (score 0):

From what you gave us, it looks like **LocalizareFarmaciiPage.xaml** is a Page. It means that it has a code-behind file (which is a .cs file).

If you want to instantiate your page in order to display it, you must add an *using* statement followed by the namespace your page file is stored in. I believe the namespace you're looking for is *ProjectName.Views*, so you want to add

```cs
using ProjectName.Views
```

with *ProjectName* being replaced by your project name of course. Then you should be able to access the LocalizareFarmaciiPage class:

```cs
LocalizareFarmaciiPage page = new LocalizareFarmaciiPage();
page.Show();
```

Also, if I may, interacting with views from services may not be a good idea, as it breaks the responsibility of the services. I believe that only ViewModels should have this responsibility (and you may want to take a look at the MVVM design pattern for this matter). Services should only be responsible for business-logic matters.